# Rust bitwise operations

Tags: rust, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I am currently trying to convert a hexadecimal value in rust (as a u16) to a RGB value stored as separate variables, all of type u8. The way I decided to do this was to use bitwise operators to get the separate values from the hex with this code:

```
Color::RGB(((hex >> (16u8)) & 0xFF) as u8, ((hex >> (8u8)) & 0xFF) as u8, ((hex) & 0xFF) as u8)
```

which resulted in an error:

```
error: this arithmetic operation will overflow
  --> src/style.rs:50:21
   |
50 |         Color::RGB(((hex >> (16u8)) & 0xFF) as u8, ((hex >> (8u8)) & 0xFF) as u8, ((hex) & 0xFF) as u8)
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ attempt to shift right by `16_u8`, which would overflow
   |
   = note: `#[deny(arithmetic_overflow)]` on by default

error: aborting due to previous error; 3 warnings emitted
```

I have solved the issue by using u16's `checked_shr(u16)`, however this makes my code more complex than I thought it would need to be, with:

```
let mut r: u8 = 0;
let mut g: u8 = 0;
let mut b: u8 = (hex as u8) & 0xFF;
if let Some(h16) = hex.checked_shr(16) {
    r = (h16 as u8) & 0xFF;
}
if let Some(h8) = hex.checked_shr(8) {
    g = (h8 as u8) & 0xFF;
}
Color::RGB(r, g, b)
```

I was wondering if there was a better way to solve the error, if I was just making a mistake in my original code, and/or if there is a better way of doing this? I was also trying to avoid turning off the `#[deny(arithmetic_overflow)]`, but that could be a mistake. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Shifting a u16 right by 16 bits leaves nothing left. There’s not enough room in u16 for 3 8 bit values. Don’t you want to use a u32 instead?

Comment: Same question as matt, how can a u16 store 3 8 bit vaules?

Comment: Ah, thank you guys, I will try fixing that mistake, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by changing the hexadecimal value from u16 to u32, Thank you to matt and Mihir who pointed that out!